# Someone made a meta tag [review-audits] - is that a better name than [audits]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Yesterday I removed the recently created tag [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) from a post here on meta. We have a preexisting tag [audits](/questions/tagged/audits) for that subject, so to keep all the audit-related questions together they should have one and the same tag.

However, on reflection, [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) seems to me like a *better* tag name than [audits](/questions/tagged/audits), since it's a more unambiguous description of the thing it's referring to.

We can rename the [audits](/questions/tagged/audits) to [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) and synonymize [audits](/questions/tagged/audits) to [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits).

Or, if folks prefer, we can just synonymize [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) to [audits](/questions/tagged/audits).

Or, we can just do nothing :)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

I believe [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) is a better tag name than [audits](/questions/tagged/audits). The main reason is what you say: it is less ambiguous. But there is another, minor reason.

[review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) will be easier to find and, *for users who are less familiar with meta*, easier to apply. This is because its name contains both "review" and "audits". When askers are typing into the tag box on their posts, or searching for tags at https://meta.askubuntu.com/tags, [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) will come up when they (start to) type "review" as well as when they (start to) type "audits".

In contrast, [audits](/questions/tagged/audits) does not come up, in either place, when one types "review" -- nor even when one types "review-audits", which perhaps explains how the [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) tag came into existence even though we already had [audits](/questions/tagged/audits). This is to say that the system matches the *entirety* of what we type into the tag box or tag search against *any part* of any existing tag name.

The reason I say this is a minor reason is that having either tag as a synonym of the other should be sufficient to guide people to the main.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I was the first one to use the [review-audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/review-audits) tag. (https://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/19292/1)

The reason why I used the [review-audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/review-audits) tag was because the Meta Stack Exchange has a tag named [review-audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/review-audits) (https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review-audits/info). Also, I didn't know that there's a tag named [audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audits).

One more thing to note is that in the [Meta Stack Exchange review audits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/846219), it's clearly mentioned that these are called review audits, not just 'audits'. So using the name 'review audits', instead of 'audits', will make things simpler for a new user on Ask Ubuntu.

I suggest you to rename the [audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audits) to [review-audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/review-audits) and synonymize [audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audits) to [review-audits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/review-audits).